# Density plots comparing two columns in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a matrix of Chip-seq results data like this for 26000 genes

```
LncRNA_ID          LncRNA_Name       Control_Raw_TagCount ICLIP_EZH2_Raw_TagCount
1        AK092525                             47908                  194887
2 ENST00000423879  RP11-12M5.1                10794                   90146
3        AF318349                              5514                   61617
4 ENST00000506392 CTC-313D10.1                  288                   40880
5 ENST00000438080 RP11-177A2.4                25005                   37380
6        AK123756                               800                   35469
```

I want to plot the counts densities of both samples, control and EZH2, that is column 3 and 4, in order to compare them. I am using R and I am very confused, mainly because I can't plot them as histograms, I get one figure with only one bar and not all the bars that I am waiting for, the same if I am interested to do a boxplot. Probably is a very silly question but I am a bit desperate

```
ezh2<-data$ICLIP_EZH2_Raw_TagCount
control<-data$Control_Raw_TagCount
hist(ezh2)# not working, i can't see distribution at all
```

Do you have any idea to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include the code you're using that's causing you problems?

Comment: The alignment looks a little off in the data frame... it may be that those columns are not being treated as numeric but are stored as factor variables with extra spaces. If `is.numeric(data$ICLIP_EZH2_Raw_TagCount)` returns `FALSE`, maybe try `as.numeric(as.character(data$ICLIP_EZH2_Raw_TagCount))`

Answer (score 0):

Box plot, where the two columns are stuck together and then split along the groups:

```
N     <- length(d$Control_Raw_TagCount)
x     <- c(d$Control_Raw_TagCount, d$ICLIP_EZH2_Raw_TagCount)
group <- rep(c("Control_Raw_TagCount", "ICLIP_EZH2_Raw_TagCount"), c(N, N))
boxplot(x ~ group)
```

Here I've assumed the data name is `d`, so adjust that to your data frame's name. If you want something like hollow histograms (see pg26 of [OpenIntro Statistics](http://www.openintro.org/stat/down/oiStat01.pdf)), the `histPlot` function in the `openintro` package will do the trick using the arguments `probability=TRUE, hollow=TRUE`:

```
# install.packages("openintro")
library(openintro)
histPlot(d$Control_Raw_TagCount, probability=TRUE, hollow=TRUE)
histPlot(d$ICLIP_EZH2_Raw_TagCount, probability=TRUE, hollow=TRUE,
         lty=3, border='red')
```

If the vertical scale isn't right, add a `ylim` argument to the first call to `histPlot` (e.g. `ylim=c(0,0.05)`).